# Angular 2 service not able to resolve all parameters

Tags: json, angular

Hi I am trying this for last two days using http reading local json file  ,not sure where the problem is

my service file

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import { Http,Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'

export class AcquirerService{





  private _url : string = "agent_output1.json";



  constructor(private _http : Http){}

  getAcquirer(){

    return this._http.get(this._url).subscribe(
      (data) => console.log(data)

    )
     // .map((response:Response) => response.json());


  }
```

my component file

```
import { Component ,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AcquirerService} from '../services/acquirer.service'


@Component({

  selector : 'acquirer-message',
  templateUrl: '../templates/acquirer.component.html',
  providers :[AcquirerService]

})

export class AcquirerComponent implements  OnInit{

  acquirer_response ;
constructor(private _acquirerService : AcquirerService){


}

  ngOnInit(){

    this._acquirerService.getAcquirer();
     // .subscribe(resAcquirerData => this.acquirer_response = resAcquirerData);


}

}
```

The error which i am getting is

```
metadata_resolver.js:972 Uncaught 
SyntaxError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AcquirerService: (?)
```

my main.ts file

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http'


if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

my app module file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule,JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app.component';
import {AcquirerComponent} from "./components/acquirer.component";
import {IssuerComponent} from "./components/issuer.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,AcquirerComponent,IssuerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent,HttpModule]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

any help will be much appreciated I am new to angular

Comment: In your service you can't return console log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add AcquirerService into providers

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
 AppComponent,AcquirerComponent,IssuerComponent
 ],
imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 FormsModule,
 HttpModule,
 JsonpModule
],
providers: [AcquirerService],
bootstrap: [AppComponent,HttpModule]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

plus add @Injectable() before AcquirerService

```
@Injectable()
export class AcquirerService{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your service file, you imported the Injectable but didn't use it. Put `@Injectable()` before the service name like this

```
@Injectable()
export class AcquirerService{
      //your code here

}
```